# Set a dashboard widget to the top?

Tags: widgets, dashboard

Instead of manually dragging and dropping a dashboard widget to the top, is there a way to code it into the widget itself so it's always at the top position?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way to **force** a dashboard widget to the top, however following [this link](https://developer.wordpress.org/apis/handbook/dashboard-widgets/#forcing-your-widget-to-the-top) should help you...in a way.

Note:

> Unfortunately this only works for people who have never re-ordered
> their widgets. Once a user has done so their existing preferences will
> override this and they will have to move your widget to the top for it
> to stay there.